# What could cause an aspx website home page to suddenly stop displaying?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

This website has had no changes since we launched it 6 months ago. It is built using ASPX and I am very inexperienced with this platform/framework.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Only the menu is displayed. I'm using Chrome:
http://goldsborospinecenter.com/

If you click on a page for example, we see the website as it is intended to look:
http://goldsborospinecenter.com/drmike.aspx

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What page is displaying? It's not `default.aspx`. Could that page be `index.html`? I checked and it seems that it is (index.html).

On that note, [check what your `default document` is](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument) - and make sure it's the one you want (likely `default.aspx` - which you can get at by clicking "home")

Comment: Yes, default.aspx is the one I want. And you are correct, it is displayed when I click HOME. However, why is it not loading as the home page? Is there a master file that controls what the default document is? It was always default.aspx and as I mentioned, nothing has changed.

Comment: Further, when I delete the index.html file, I get a server error. This sure isn't what I'm used to with php. How do I get the default.aspx to load automatically?

Comment: @webraven As above, you have to set the default document on IIS or `web.config` in your site (see the link I gave). Your host may have pre-set configurations that say "index" is the default doc. That's also why you'll see an error if you delete it (because there is no default doc). More to do with settings than anything. As to how/why it changed, well, only you or hour host can answer that....

Comment: EdSF - Thank you. Something must have changed on the hosting side, but they were unaware of it. They did provide some code and I was able to cross check it with the link you provided above.

Here's what I did to get it working. Placed this code within the <configuration> tags on my web.config file:

   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="default.aspx" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>

Solved! Thanks again!